# Bash: `-su: $*: unbound variable` with `set -u`

Tags: bash, freebsd

This is a FreeBSD 7.x system running GNU bash version 4.0.

In Bash, the `set -u` option can force a shell to print an error if it encounters an unset variable, like this:

```
$ set -u
$ echo $THISISUNSET
-su: THISISUNSET: unbound variable
$ echo $?
1
```

However, I am also encountering this same error for $*:

```
$ echo $*
-su: $*: unbound variable
$ echo $?
1
$ echo $@
-su: $@: unbound variable
```

The Bash Manual [4.3.1 The Set Builtin](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#The-Set-Builtin) specifically says that `set -u` ignores $* and $@:

> -u Treat unset variables and parameters other than the special parameters ‘@’ or ‘*’ as an error when performing parameter expansion.
>   An error message will be written to the standard error, and a
>   non-interactive shell will exit.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a bug in older versions of bash, specifically 4.0​β2 patchlevel d to 4.0 patchlevel m. From the [changelog](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/CHANGES) from 4.0 to 4.1​α:

> n.  Fixed the behavior of `set -u` to conform to the latest Posix interpretation:
>       every expansion of an unset variable except $@ and $* will cause the
>       shell to exit.

This behavior was introduced in ​4.0β2 because the previous (and now again current) behavior was thought to be buggy:

> d.  Fixed a bug that caused expansions of $@ and $* to not exit the shell if
>       the -u option was enabled and there were no posititional parameters.